# operating R dataframe using variables for the column name

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I want to store a column name in a variable and operate a dataframe based on that column name.
For example if a I have two columns named `car_sales` and `airplane_sales`. I have a variable `var` that a user sets to say `car_sales`. i then calculate a new column like so:

```
calc_col <- paste0(var,"_delta")

df$calc_col <- abs(df$var - lag(df$var ,12))
```

The `var` will change based on user input, so the resulting column will also change

How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```r
df[[calc_col]] <- abs(df[[var]] - lag(df[[var]], 12))
```

Comment: Would this work if we want to use the dyplr filtering syntax too? Like `df %>% filter(df[[var]] == 1)` ?